# Selenium error + how to get text in prompt box

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code shorted

```
driver.get('http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'exportSave').click()
info = driver.switch_to.alert
```

now I get a error Message: unexpected alert open:
I've another question
[Here is a popup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If30t.png)

I want to get the prompt inside the box where we can write using sendKeys method how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is working for me, this is in `java` I know you can easily change it in `python`.

```
   driver.get('http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/');
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@id='exportSave'])[1]")).click();
    
    String s = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
    System.out.println(s);
    
    
    driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture the alert message.

```
   String s = driver.switch_to.alert();
   s.getText();
```

To send some data to alert box.

```
driver.switch_to.alert().sendKeys("Text");
```

Comment: info = driver.switch_to.alert().getText()
TypeError: 'Alert' object is not callable

Comment: I updated the answer please check it now.

Comment: String info = driver.switch_to.alert()
           ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I added the complete solution in java it's working for me, I know you can change it in python